# Error parsing date from SQLite with PySpark

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read some tables from a SQLite db file to work with them with PySpark. I'm using the following code, and it works well with the tables which do not contain a date.

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
        .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable='table_name',
                 url='jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/database.db')\
        .load()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")
spark.sql("select * from table_name").show(n=5)
df.printSchema()

//Exit
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- initial_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- final_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- ref_id: string (nullable = true)
```

The problem comes when a table contains a date. I get a parsing date error when trying to execute `spark.sql("select * from table_name").show(n=5)`

***Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing date***

***Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-12-18" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)***

¿How can I parse the date to a valid format for PySpark?

Comment: I'd try to cast all of the dates as strings before displaying or making any other actions on that dataframe, and then try to cast those strings in spark as dates.

Comment: Thank you @matkurek but I'm getting the same error. I have casted all dates to string (and checked it with printSchema()), but the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution that worked is to use the option customSchema to read the fields as String.

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
        .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable='table_name',
                 url='jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/database.db')\
        .option("customSchema", "column1 STRING, column2 STRING")\
        .load()
```